# Como criar uma classe com inferência de tipo que possa ter um tipo padrão em C#

Tags: c#, classes, genéricos, inferência

Estou criando uma classe onde eu faço a inferência de tipo, como no exemplo abaixo:

```cs
public class Foo<T> {
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de eu deixar definido para T um tipo padrão como `string`? Minha intenção é poder usar das duas formas abaixo:

```cs
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a = new Foo<int>();
        var b = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Respondi agora. Acho que pode resolver sua implementação. Veja lá.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não está fazendo inferência de tipo na declaração da classe, está fazendo na declaração das variáveis quando instancia a classe. Está só usando um tipo genérico na classe.

O que deseja é um argumento padrão no tipo genérico, então quando for instanciar a classe que exige que seja informado qual o tipo para a classe ser criada não precise dizer qual é o tipo, porque afinal, provavelmente, quase todos os casos é o mesmo tipo a ser usado, exemplificado `string`. Faz todo sentido querer isso, mas ao contrário do C++, C# não tem isto e não tem previsão para ter tão cedo (mas [você pode pedir](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues)), terá que fazer na mão. Mas convenhamos que não é o fim do mundo. Se permitisse seria algo assim:

```
public class Foo<T = string> {
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Existem alguns casos que um método genérico pode ter o tipo inferido pelo argumento usado dentro dele, mas não é o que deseja.

Você pode criar um alias com `using` e evitar o uso completo:

```
using Foo = Foo<string>;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var a = new Foo<int>();
        var b = new Foo();
    }
}
public class Foo<T> {
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cy0t6Y). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KrSg9e). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/Inference.cs).

Também é possível criar uma classe que encapsula isto como mostrado nas outras respostas, mas isto pode ser problemático para um ganho muito pequeno, não acho legal criar uma hierarquia para facilitar a digitação em vez de fazer para modelar melhor o problema, me parece abuso do mecanismo, ainda que funcione. Mesmo o `using`, que não traz problemas graves a não ser uma redução na legibilidade, só é usado em casos complexos.

Comment: =[... infelizmente vou ter que continuar fazendo uma classe sem generalização e extender o tipo dela, dando um new pra propriedade...

Comment: Sim, isso você pode fazer, mas não tem na da linguagem que permita isso. Particularmente de forma geral eu prefiro fazer assim do que criar uma classe que cria uma camada, uma indireção. No máximo eu faria um alias com `using`, sabe fazer, né?

Comment: Não sabia que eu podia usar o `using` dessa forma...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma classe com o tipo genérico "fixado".

É preciso tomar cuidado porque isso abre brechas para alguém modificar a classe derivada e ela não ficar de acordo com a original.

```
class Foo : Foo<string> 
{
}
```

Exemplo executável:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Foo<int> { Bar = 1 };
        var b = new Foo { Bar = "Hey" };

        Console.WriteLine(a.Bar);
        Console.WriteLine(b.Bar);
    }
}

class Foo<T> 
{
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}

class Foo : Foo<string> 
{
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDHqAm)</sup>

Comment: sim hoje é o que eu faço, mas a resposta do @Maniero me deu um feeback melhor do porquê não posso fazer isso...

Answer (score 2):

Me baseando na sua necessidade de instancia as classes com `var a = new Foo<int>();` ou  `var b = new Foo();` a implementação abaixo resolve.

**Note que o código da `class Program` está igual ao so seu exemplo.**

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}

//Aqui você define o tipo padrão. 
public class Foo : Foo<string> { }

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a = new Foo<int>();
        var b = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Veja o exemplo em execução aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YmJRtk

Comment: sim hoje é o que eu faço, mas a resposta do @Maniero me deu um feeback melhor do porquê não posso fazer isso...